# How to show where the cxf fault is intercepted?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I am getting a 400 response from my service for CXF fault, I can't find where the 400 was set,

I searched everywhere, the exception mapper was not hit for this fault,
the response was a tomcat formated html

something started with Apache Tomcat/8.0.46 - Error report

which made me believe it was not mapped to a proper response,

but I thought it should be 500 instead of 400,

Is there any way to show where the interceptor might be, like a verbose option for the debugger console output in CXF?

Thanks a million!

```
05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@e16a6b5 was created. Current flow:
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  marshal [JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor]

05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@51645fab
05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@33fad37 to phase prepare-send-ending
05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@e16a6b5 was modified. Current flow:
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  marshal [JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@21747905
05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@21747905
05 Mar 2019 09:58:36,402  WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-4] - x-dxe-requestid=bd5f3c71-0fe7-4ed7-80f6-46049db8b26d Exception in handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@21747905
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.dxe.comm.domain._2012_11_01.ComTransaction.setTransactionNetworkId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
```

Answer (score 0):

found out it was set in our own code, in: javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter which is a terrible mistake.